# SFRadialGauge widget disappearing after wrapping it with another widget

Tags: flutter

I was working on a project that needs to display a gouge to the user; for that purpose I'm using the syncfusion_flutter_gauge package. I used SizedBox widget to change the size of the SFRadialGauge. the problem is as soon as I give values to the top and left parameters of the Positioned Widget the SFRadialGauge widget disappears.

```
Positioned(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: SfRadialGauge(
            animationDuration: 1,
            enableLoadingAnimation: true,
            axes: <RadialAxis>[
              RadialAxis(
                minimum: 13.5,
                maximum: 34.5,
                ranges: [
                  GaugeRange(startValue: 13.5, endValue: 18.5, color: Colors.orange.shade500,),
                  GaugeRange(startValue: 18.5, endValue: 24.5, color: Colors.green.shade500,),
                  GaugeRange(startValue: 24.5, endValue: 29.5, color: Colors.yellow),
                  GaugeRange(startValue: 29.5, endValue: 34.5, color: Colors.red),
                ],
                pointers:  [
                  NeedlePointer(
                    value: 18.5, 
                    needleColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    
                  )
                ],
                annotations: const <GaugeAnnotation>[
                  GaugeAnnotation(widget: SizedBox(
                    child: Text("19.0",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                    angle: 90,
                    positionFactor: 0.8,
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I tried to remove the Positioned widget and used the Center widget to make the SFRadialGauge widget at the center of the stack and it worked correctly. but I don't want it to be centered